# This server is not the leader for that topic-partition in KafkaJS package

Tags: node.js, typescript, apache-kafka, kafkajs

I am using the kafkaJS library to connect Kafka consumer, below is the configuration

```
  private createKafkaConsumer(): Consumer {
    const kafka = new Kafka({
      logLevel: logLevel.WARN,
      brokers: this.kafkaHost,
      connectionTimeout: 10000,
      requestTimeout: 25000,
      retry: {
        initialRetryTime: 100,
        retries: 8,
      },
    });
    const consumer = kafka.consumer({
      groupId: this.groupId,
      sessionTimeout: 60000,
      rebalanceTimeout: 60000,
      heartbeatInterval: 3000,
      allowAutoTopicCreation: false,
      maxWaitTimeInMs: 5000,
      maxBytes: 1024 * 10
    });
    return consumer;
  }
```

I am getting this error

```
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2022-10-16T12:29:57.236Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Response Fetch(key: 1, version: 10)","broker":"b-1.ccss-prod-pulse-msk.5jyfxf.c3.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:9092","clientId":"kafkajs","error":"This server is not the leader for that topic-partition","correlationId":2301,"size":162}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2022-10-16T12:29:57.258Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Response Fetch(key: 1, version: 10)","broker":"b-1.ccss-prod-pulse-msk.5jyfxf.c3.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:9092","clientId":"kafkajs","error":"This server is not the leader for that topic-partition","correlationId":2302,"size":162}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2022-10-16T12:29:57.275Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Response Fetch(key: 1, version: 10)","broker":"b-1.ccss-prod-pulse-msk.5jyfxf.c3.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:9092","clientId":"kafkajs","error":"This server is not the leader for that topic-partition","correlationId":2303,"size":162}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2022-10-16T12:29:57.331Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Response OffsetCommit(key: 8, version: 5)","broker":"b-2.ccss-prod-pulse-msk.5jyfxf.c3.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:9092","clientId":"kafkajs","error":"Specified group generation id is not valid","correlationId":6017,"size":86}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2022-10-16T12:29:57.334Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Response Fetch(key: 1, version: 10)","broker":"b-1.ccss-prod-pulse-msk.5jyfxf.c3.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:9092","clientId":"kafkajs","error":"This server is not the leader for that topic-partition","correlationId":2304,"size":162}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2022-10-16T12:29:59.872Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Consumer] Crash: KafkaJSNonRetriableError: Specified group generation id is not valid","groupId":"in-EW-Maintenance-Hourmeter.1","stack":"KafkaJSNonRetriableError: Specified group generation id is not valid\n    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/kafkajs/src/retry/index.js:55:18\n    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)"}
[root@ip-10-213-116-19 ~]#
```

have anyone come across this issue?

Comment: Well, 1) does the topic you're trying to use exist? 2) Are you missing authentication settings? Also, what's the value for the group id?

Comment: @OneCricketeer  1. It exists, 2. No auth required 3. How to find the value of group id